# How can I get three columns, sibling divs, each expand to fill its parent?

Tags: html, stylesheet

I have been searching forever. Sorry, I am pretty desperate at this point so I thought I would ask here. Below is an HTML sample. When column B is longer than a single page (viewport, sorry I am not sure on the correct terminology here) then A and C are not expanding in height to fill the container div. They fill the entire page but stop at a single page length even if column B is longer than a single page. Any ideas, i have been pulling my hair out. I have been playing around with height and min-height and nothing seems to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            html, body 
            {
                height: 100%;
                background-color: gray;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }

            #container
            {
                height: 100%;
                margin: auto;
                padding: 0px;
                width: 610px;
            }

            #a
            {
                width: 5px;
                min-height: 100%;
                float: left;
                background-color: yellow;
            }

            #b
            {
                width: 600px;
                background-color: Blue;
                float:left;
                min-height: 100%;
            }

            #c
            {
                width: 5px;
                float:left;
                min-height: 100%;
                background-color: green;
            }
        </style>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="a"></div>
            <div id="b">
                <p>more</p>
                <p>more</p>
                <p>more</p>
                <p>more</p>
                <p>more</p>
                <p>more</p>
                <p>more</p>
                <p>more</p>
                <p>more</p>
                <p>more</p>
                <p>more</p>
                <p>more</p>
                <p>more</p>
                <p>more</p>
                <p>more</p>
                <p>more</p>
                <p>more</p>
                <p>more</p>
                <p>more</p>
                <p>more</p>
                <p>more</p>
                <p>more</p>
                <p>more</p>
                <p>more</p>
                <p>more</p>
                <p>more</p>
                <p>more</p>
                <p>more</p>
                <p>more</p>
                <p>more</p>
                <p>more</p>
                <p>more</p>
                <p>more</p>
                <p>more</p>
                <p>more</p>
                <p>more</p>
            </div>
            <div id="c"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:
Before I waste someone's time explaining to me about grabbing one pixel horizontally and then tiling is that the designer gave me a vertical gradient. Starting dark at top and ending lighter. That as well as a shadow effect. The shadow runs horizontally. So there is no way to slice this and then use a clever use of tiling as far as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you seen the [faux columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) trick?

Comment: Yes I have. I would have done this but unfortunately the designer gave me a gradient fill that is vertical, so slicing vertically doesn't work. I have to slice horizontally.

Comment: then just don't set a repeat.

Comment: But then I am going to have a large background image. BUT I suppose in today's world of fast internet speeds does it matter if I am downloading two biggish images?

Comment: It really depends on your target market.  Internal corporate: usually no.  Mom and pop running dial up in the middle of kansas: yes.  That said, check out this link: for info about high speed penetration rates http://articlet.com/article791.html

Answer (score 1):

By far, the easiest way of doing this is to use a single row table instead of the divs.  Table's may not be the uber cool way of doing things, but at the end of the day they just work for a whole lot less code than trying to achieve the same thing with css.

Comment: I have just got it right using tables myself. I think it is such a hacky way of doing it BUT I am at the point where I am thinking whatever gets the job done. So If no one can get a solution using CSS and divs then I will to choose this as the right answer.